# Emit event to azure event hub in a loop

Tags: azure, python-3.8, azure-eventhub

We store large (200mb to 5GB) CSV files in azure blob.
We download them to our container.
loop through each row, extract one field which is a JSON payload
Convert JSON to AVRO Byte Array Serialize it
we serialize based on and by looking up the schema in the confluent schema registry.
We then Emit the payload as an event into EventHubs
currently, we are calling it row by row. see code below. it takes about 1 sec/ row.
check the emit_msg(send_msg) function

```
def process_files() :
    filenames = find_csv_filenames("./fp")
    print("\n")
    print('Total files found = ', len(filenames))
    print(filenames)
    print("\n")
    if len(filenames) > 0 :
    for f in filenames:
    start = time.time()
    print("now working on ....", f)

        with open(f) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            line_count = 0
            #csv_reader can contain upto 50 million rows
            for row in csv_reader:
                if line_count == 0:

                    line_count += 1
                    send_msg = "Line # is " + str(line_count) + " And Line value is : " + row[0]
                    print(send_msg)
                    #send to event hub
                    emit_msg(send_msg)
                    line_count += 1
            print("")
            print(f'Processed {line_count:,} lines.')
            end = time.time()
            print(f'Completed processing in {round(end-start)} seconds.')
            print("______________________________________________________")
            print("\n")

def emit_msg(emit_string):
    client = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(eh_cs, eventhub_name=eh_name)
    event_data_batch = client.create_batch()
    event_data_batch.add(EventData(emit_string))
    with client:
        client.send_batch(event_data_batch)
```

We tried to vectorize, see below code. Still takes the same time.

```
def process_file(filename) :
    start = time.time()
    print(f"working on .... {filename} \n")
    df = dd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[6])
    print(df.head(4))
    print("")
    print(f'Processed {df.shape[0].compute(scheduler="processes"):,} lines.\n')
    df[df.columns[0]].apply(emit_msg, meta=('Order ID', 'int') ).compute(scheduler="processes")
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Completed processing in {round(end-start)} seconds.\n')
    print("______________________________________________________")
    print("\n")
```

Our immediate bottleneck is in publishing to event hub. This currently taking 1 sec/message emit.
Our SLA is to publish 100mb/sec.  i.e. 100,000 messages per sec.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks as always!